# uploading local logs to loki through promtail

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I wanted to upload local .logs to grafana through loki using promtail.
My promtail shows that the files are in, but in Grafana, it is not shown.

[image: promtail files]

[image: files not in loki]

I've tried configurating the loki and promtail config files.
There hasn't been much results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your promtail-local-config.yaml
2. Change the `__path__` to the local path of your logs
3. Execute this command:

   ```
   ./promtail-linux-amd64 -client.url http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push -config.file=promtail-local-config.yaml -positions.file=/tmp/positions.yaml
   ```